# CakePHP: calling an external Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp-1.3

I have the following code that works as shown here: `http://jsfiddle.net/rBd53/12/`

HTML/JS code in one file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBlocks = new Array(
        'Select from the list to change this box',
        'Text block two',
        'Text block three'); 

    function changeText(form) {
        var ind = form.qwer.selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind]; 
    }
</script>

<form>
    <select name="qwer" onChange="changeText(this.form);">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div id="display">Select from the list to change this box</div> 
</form>
```

How do I change this code to make it work properly with CakePHP 1.3? I have created a `test_js.js` file under `app/webroot/js` and put the `<script>...</script>` portion in there. I also have `echo $scripts_for_layout;` in `app/views/layouts/default.ctp` in the `<head>`.

I'm guessing stuff in my element (.ctp) file is incorrect. The dropdown menu and text below appear, but the text is not dynamically changed according to the option selected. I did the following.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('test_js', array('inline'=>false)); ?>
<form>
<select name="qwer" onChange="changeText(this.form);">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="display">Select from the list to change this box</div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seemed to have been a cashing issue. It is working as it was, and this is what I have.

`app\webroot\js\test_js.js`:

```
var textBlocks = new Array(
    'Select from the list to change this box',
    'Text block two',
    'Text block three'); 

function changeText(form) {
    var ind = form.qwer.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind]; 
}
```

In the view element page (.ctp):

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('test_js', array('inline'=>false)); ?>
<form>
    <select name="qwer" onChange="changeText(this.form);">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
<br>
<div id="display">Select from the list to change this box</div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're calling the helper method wrong, it only takes 2 parameters:

```
echo $this->Html->script('test_js', array('inline'=>false));
```

Also, if that doesn't work, it would be nice to know exactly which warning you're getting...

Comment: Hi, I removed the null argument, and the script is being placed in the header as it should. There is no error at this point, and nothing happens when the options in the dropdown menu is selected.

Comment: 1. There should be no `<script></script>` tags on the external js file; 2. You need an `window.onload = function() { /* your code here */ };` handler, or to place your code just before `</body>` instead of the head. The code is trying to reference html elements that do not exist when the js is interpreted.

Comment: I removed the `<script>` tag in the external JS file. As for the rest of your suggestion, I'm not getting it to work still. A working JSfiddle example where the HTML and Javascript is separated would be nice..

Comment: This is strange. My code actually seems to work. I was just refreshing the page with F5, but when I resubmitted the page, it started working as I intended.

Comment: Forget what I said about `window.onload`, it's not necessary in this case. Your code should be working (see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/opCyn). Oh, now I see you just said it is. That was probably the browser cache then.